# How to filter the sku empty and remove all the coincidense that the same order number

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4, mule-esb

There is an array of parent elements that you need filter and remove if the sky are empty and get the number and remove all the coincidences of the principal array.

Input:

```
[{
    "number": "7358",
    "sku": "301-01"
}, {
    "number": "7358",
    "sku": "301-02"
}, {
    "number": "7359",
    "sku": ""
}, {
    "number": "7359",
    "sku": "301-04"
}, {
    "number": "7356",
    "sku": ""
}, {
    "number": "7356",
    "sku": "301-05"
}, {
    "number": "7356",
    "sku": "301-07"
}]
```

Output:

```
[{
    "number": "7358",
    "sku": "301-01"
}, {
    "number": "7358",
    "sku": "301-02"
}]
```

In Output we only find the elements that complied with having their sku with content.

Comment: Not sure if your ask is clear.. What do you mean by having their sku with content?

Comment: Can you clarify why the output should not contain these elements?
`{"number": "7356","sku": "301-05"}, {"number": "7356","sku": "301-07"}`

Comment: From what i understood of the ask, since there is an object present in the input with "number" as 7356 and "sku" being "" it needs to be filtered out. The only object that would make it to the final output would be where every instance of the object for a given "number" has "sku" != "" .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this script:

The idea is to collect all `number`(s) where the sku is "" and create an array out of these. After that you can iterate through the payload and filter out objects where the number in the object is present in the array created in the previous step.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var atleastOneEmptySku = (payload filter ($.sku == ""))..number
---
payload filter (!(atleastOneEmptySku contains $.number))
```